# Fetch column schema from tables of mysql datatable

Tags: c#, mysql, information-schema

I want to fetch column schema with full details from Mysql Database.

I am having two tables where Customer table schema is like as

[image]

And another table Orders table schema is like this

[image]

I want to fetch these column schema with respect to my join query which is

```
using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("Server=xxxx;Uid=is;Pwd=password;Database=mydatabse"))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT a.CustomerID, a.PostalCode, b.Freight, b.ShippedDate 
                                                FROM orders b, customers a 
                                                WHERE a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID Limit 5;", myConnection))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        using (MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add("Customers");

            mdr.Read();
            DataRow dr;
            dt.Columns.Add("ColName");
            dt.Columns.Add("ColType");

            for (int k = 0; k <= mdr.FieldCount - 1; k++)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ColName"] = mdr.GetName(k);
                dr["ColType"] = mdr.GetDataTypeName(k);
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need the full detail schema of the selected columns which I have used in join query.
I have used `GetDataTypeName()` to retrieve column type but it only returns datatype.

I found this query

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nsightsmysqldata' AND TABLE_NAME = 'customers';
```

which returns all detail relating to that table but I need only those column details which I had used in join query above.

Please provide me possible solution.

Comment: NO, you can't get schema information like that way. What you can probably do is: get the entire schema and store it in a in-memory object and based on your query (columns) and you can manipulate the schema and get the required information.

Comment: BTW, don't post pic rather include the text schema which is much more readable.

Comment: Also, do NOT post your code with database credentials!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can do that with the 
[connection object](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_GetSchema.htm)

Well at least it worked for me in powershell.

`$conn.GetSchema("Columns")` will return every column schema in the current database as a DataTable